# Excel - Return Specific Values from Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

new to the forum and new to Excel in general.  My buddies and I are creating a golf stats sheet and we wanted to see if there is a formula to pull specific data from specific values.  Here is the example:

Sheet 1(Totals)
Sheet 2(Course 1)
Sheet 3(Course 2)
etc.

The Totals sheet will provide the list of players in Rows and in the first column will be Course names that can be selected as a List.

The other sheets (courses) will basically have score cards for that course.  It'll inidicate names of who played that course along with course scores in a specific cell. i.e. Cell A1 would have the player name and B1 would have the total score.

What i would like is a formula in which, once a specific Course is selected in the Totals sheet, it'll return the specific player with its score.

So if i were to select Course 1 (Cell A1) in a drop down menu, the formula would look in the workbook and find the name Course 1 and return the player name is Cell B1 with the score in Cell C1.

I hope this didn't confuse anyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a code for me site.  Please post any attempts, test data and expected output in your original question and let us know what specifically is the error.  SO is a place where a community can help with problems in existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming players are in A2 and down and the course name is in B1. Put this in B2 and drag.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!A:B"),2,FALSE)
```